# Subplot with two panels (plot and pie)

Tags: python, plot, merge, pie-chart, subplot

I would like to merge two graphs or panels using subplot. I tried using thisi script, but I didn't get that I would like. I have one plot and one pie. On the image, the plot should be to left and pie to right. How can I do?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
#pie
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
sns.countplot(df['data_si_o_no'])
#pie
ax1.pie(df['data_si_o_no'].value_counts(),
            labels=['Not Disaster', 'Disaster'],
            autopct='%1.2f%%',
            shadow=True,
            explode=(0.05, 0),
            startangle=60)
fig1.suptitle('Distribution of the data', fontsize=24)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to note:

1. To plot 2 subplots next to each other, the subplots should be `1,2` as that represents the `# rows, # columns`.
2. The `ax1` will be broken into `ax1[0], ax1[1]` for the two plots. I have just used ax instead of ax1
3. As you are using seaborn for one of the count plot, you need to define `ax=ax[0]` while providing the parameters, so that matplotlib knows it is the first plot.
4. For the matplotlib pie plot/chart, you need to use `ax[1]=..`

With these changes, you should be able to see the required plots. Note that, as there was no data provided, I used dummy data (Female/Male) from Titanic dataset instead.

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5)) # 1 row, 2 columns
#pie
sns.countplot(df['data_si_o_no'], ax=ax[0])
#pie
ax[1]=plt.pie(df['data_si_o_no'].value_counts(),
            labels=['male', 'female'],
            autopct='%1.2f%%',
            shadow=True,
            explode=(0.05, 0),
            startangle=60)
fig1.suptitle('Distribution of the data', fontsize=24)
```

**Plot**

[image]